# How can I find out default placeholder setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a drop down menu, that will be next to a box with a placeholder within it. I would like both of the text within the boxes to appear the same. I would like to know, how do I find out the default properties from the text box, so that I may use those properties in my drop down menu?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Gray Default">

<select>
  <option>Black Default
  </option>
</select>
```

I want the style of both boxes to appear the same. I just don't know how to find the exact default settings

Comment: what did you try? use `css`

Comment: I can use css, but I can't match the properties exactly, without knowing what they are. I do not know what font is used, the size, or exact color. Is there some resources I could use to find out what these properties are?

Comment: @RobertCrenshaw The placeholder text is gray, the dropdown text is black. Do you want to make them both black?

Comment: Yeah, the color is "gray" by default. To change this you can check out the link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Comment: You can use the DOM method `getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check default browser styles you can use `window.getComputedStyle()`. Unfortunately, each browser uses its own pseudoclass/pseudoelement name for placeholders:

> - WebKit and Blink (Safari, Google Chrome, Opera 15+) are using a pseudo-element:
>     [`::-webkit-input-placeholder`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21227).
> - Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 is using a pseudo-class: [`:-moz-placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:-moz-placeholder) (*one* colon).
> - Mozilla Firefox 19+ is using a pseudo-element: [`::-moz-placeholder`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737786),
>     but the old selector will still work for a while.
> - Internet Explorer 10 is using a pseudo-class: [`:-ms-input-placeholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx).
>
> IE up to version 9 and
>   [Opera](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206060908/http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=841252&t=1296553904&page=1#comment8072202)
>   up to version 12 do not support any CSS selector for placeholders.

(taken from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/5114473))

### Example code

I used this code to discover that on my Firefox placeholder has black color and opacity of 0.54.

```js
var firstInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    placeholderStyles = window.getComputedStyle(firstInput, '::-moz-placeholder');
console.log('Color: ' + placeholderStyles.getPropertyValue('color'));
console.log('Opacity: ' + placeholderStyles.getPropertyValue('opacity'));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="blah, blah">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
select {
  color:  rgb(0,0,0);
  opacity:0.54;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Gray Default" >

<select>
  <option>Changed to Gray
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is purple, not the default gray

Comment: How do I check the color of the placeholder like you just did is my questions?

Comment: try colorzila addon in google chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon